# Execute a method from a class in mainActivity (Android)

Tags: java, android, methods, call

I m trying to execute a method from a class called QrScann in the MainActivity class when the user click on a button but everytime the app crash as soon as I click the button and it gives me this log crash output

```
 06-02 17:00:24.890    7067-7084/t.n.app W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-02 17:00:24.890    7067-7084/t.n.app W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb3ee6da0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
06-02 17:00:27.473    7067-7067/t.n.app D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
06-02 17:00:27.474    7067-7067/t.n.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: snet.tuberlin.app, PID: 7067
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3745)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3706)
            at snet.tuberlin.app.QRCode.scanQR(QRCode.java:23)
            at snet.tuberlin.app.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:48)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

and this is the class that has the method(Scanner) which i want to execute :

```
public class QrScann extends Activity {

static final String ACTION_SCAN = "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN";

public void Scanner(View v) {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_SCAN);
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        showDialog(QrScann.this, "No Scanner Found", "Download a scanner code activity?", "Yes", "No").show();
    }
}
```

The class has other method as well.
And finelly this is what i have done in my MainActivity class :

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {



public Button Scanner;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Scanner =(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonScanQR);
        Scanner.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Intent QrScann = new Intent(this, QrScann.class);
        //startActivity(QrScann );
        QrScann QRScanner =new QrScann();
        QRScanner.Scanner(v);

    }
}
```

I would really appreciate an explanation of what I may be missing.

Comment: Is your QrScann a declared activity in your Manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class QrScann {

static final String ACTION_SCAN = "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN";
private MainActivity mContext;
public QrScann(MainActivity context) {
   mContext = context;
}

public void Scanner(View v) {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_SCAN);
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        mContext.startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        //show dialog is deprecated , try DialogFragments
        mContext.showDialog(QrScann.this, "No Scanner Found", "Download a scanner code activity?", "Yes", "No").show();
    }
}
```

From Activity

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        QrScann QRScanner =new QrScann(this);
        QRScanner.Scanner(v);

    }
```

Comment: Thank you alot ! i tried to implement it but i got an error (can not resolve method) concerning startActivityforResult and showDialog too

Comment: Thank you so much you saved my day :)
Now i only have to figure wh the showDialog isnt working but otherweise it works fine

Comment: I wish i could!!! i need 16 reputation for that :/ but i promis as soon as i get them i will do it :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't create "`new`" Activities, you start them with `Intents` by providing the class, then handle your actions from within the lifecycles method by providing extras and actions from within your starting Intent.

So, basically, `QrScann QRScanner = new QRScann();` is the wrong way to attempt to create a system component.  You should use `Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, QrScann.class);` and provide actions/extras in the intent.

Comment: Should i do it this way then on the Onclick ? 
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, QrScann.class);
Intent..Scanner(v);

Comment: It looks like you could get rid of your other Activity all together, and launch your activityForResult from within your onClick, then just look for the onActivityResult(...) call in your MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `QrScann` class is not a valid `Activity`. You cannot simply instantiate a new `Activity` class with the `new` keyword- you need to allow the Activity to be created by the framework and go through the Activity lifecycle by starting it via `startActivity()` on a valid Context.

It looks like you made `QrScann` extend Activity for the sole purpose of being able to call `startActivityForResult()`. Instead, `QrScann` should get a reference to its `MainActivity` and call `startActivityForResult()` on that, or call back to the `MainActivity`.

Comment: Can you plz provide me with more practical information ?

Comment: What part do you want more information on? `Activity` objects are managed by the system- you should never create an instance of an `Activity` class yourself.

Comment: So what should i do exactly ? I mean do i have to change the QrScann class ?

Comment: Yes, change it so that it does not extend `Activity`. You can pass a reference to your `MainActivity` to the `Scanner()` method and call `startActivityForResult()` on that.

Comment: I got your point but i dont have the knowledge to apply what you said since i m a beginner i will appreciat it if you provide me with a solution 
I know i m asking alot but i have been working on this error for the last 8 hours with no progress

Comment: Looks like [r7v just rewrote the `QrScann` class](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30603260/1253844) the way I was imagining it

Comment: Yes but somehow when i tried to implement it it can not resolve startActivityforResult and showDialog methods

Answer (score 0):

You can't just instance an `Activity` like `new QrScann()`, you have to do it this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, QrScann.class);
startActivity(intent);
```